# Is there a way to use more than 64 uniform vectors in a fragment shader? or alternative?

Tags: ios, glsl, shader, gpuimage

I use GPUImage in my project. and I want to pass an array with 2304 integer to the fragment shader. but [OpenGL ES 2.0 on the PowerVR SGX is limit only 64 uniform vectors for fragment shader](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH106-SW1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are your hardware limits, then those are your hardware limits. That's why they're called hardware *limits*.

There are alternatives to using uniforms. For example, you could use a 1D texture (or a 2D texture that has a height of 1), where the texels of your texture are the values you need. Granted, if the SGX's texture size limit is 2048, you'll need some fudging to make it work with 2304 values.

Comment: It's possible to use 2D texture (`coordX = index % (int)textureWidth; coordY = index / (int)textureWidth`)

Comment: The SGX535 was limited to 2048, but the 543 (iPad 2/new iPad, 4S) can use 4096.

Comment: Limits can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html